# Touch scrolling on site exposes white space

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a responsive single page site which has a menu that can be brought out from the side of the page using the following code:

```
    if($('#slide-menu-panel').css("margin-right") == "0px"){
    $('#slide-menu-panel').animate({"margin-right": '-=300'});
}else{
    $('#slide-menu-panel').animate({"margin-right": '+=300'});
}
```

and the following css for the menu element:

```
    #slide-menu-panel{
    width:300px;
    z-index: 51;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    visibility: visible;
    right:0px;
    margin-right: -300px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
}
```

This is usually fine, but on iphones (not androids or ipads) touch and dragging on the menu can pull the whole page out from the side leaving a white space to the right of the page.

I am using the following in my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

And I am using the code from http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/ to scroll backgrounds when the user touches and drags on the main page, but not on the menu.

How can I prevent the user from dragging the page away from the right side and exposing white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this was happening, but I prevented it by handling the ontouchstart event on the menu and discarding the input.